# Why docker (Container-based technologies) are useful

Tags: containers, virtualization, docker

Lately I have been looking into docker and the usefulness it can provide to a SaaS company. I have spent some time learning about how to containerize apps and learning briefly about what docker and containers are. I have some problems understanding the usefulness of this technology. I have watched some videos from dockercon and it seems like everyone is talking about how docker makes deployment easy and how you deploy in your dev environment is guaranteed to run in production. However, I have some questions:

1. Deploying containers directly to production from the dev environment means that developers should develop inside containers which are the same containers that will run on production. This is practically not possible because developers like to develop on their fancy MACs with IDEs. Developers will revolt if they are told to ssh into containers and develop their code inside. So how does that work in companies that currently use docker?
2. If we assume that the development workflow will not change. Developers will develop locally and push their code into a repo or something. So where is the "containerizing the app" fits within the workflow?
3. Also if developers do not develop within containers, then the "what you develop is what you deploy and is guaranteed to work" assumption is violated. If this is the case, then I can only see that the only benefit docker offers is isolation, which is the same thing virtualization offer, of course with a lower overhead. So my question here would be, is the low overhead the only advantage docker has on virtualization? or are other things I dont see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can write the code outside of a container and transfer it into the container in many different ways. Some examples include:

   - Code locally and include the source when you `docker build` by using an `ADD` or `COPY` statement as part of the `Dockerfile`
   - Code locally and push your code to a source code repository like GitHub and then have the build process pull the code into the container as part of `docker build`
   - Code locally and mount your local source code directory as a shared volume with the container.

   The first two allow you to have exactly the same build process in production and development. The last example would not be suitable for production, but could be quickly converted to production with an `ADD` statement (i.e. the first example)
2. In the Docker workflow, Developers can create both source code (which gets stored and shared in a repository like git, mercurial, etc) and a ready-to-run container, which gets stored and shared via a repository like https://registry.hub.docker.com or a [local registry](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker-registry).
3. The containerized running code that you develop and test is exactly what can go to production. That's one advantage. In addition you get isolation, interesting container-to-container networking, and tool integration with a growing class of devops tools for creating, maintaining and deploying containers.